# AWS: Limit which IAM roles can be attached to an EC2 instance by different IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Im trying to figure out if this is possible. I have 2 IAM users. I would like each one to be able to start/stop the same EC2 instance but have each IAM user be able to attach a different IAM role to this one EC2 instance. In other words, user1 should **only** be able to attach role1 to this ec2 instance, while user2 should **only** be able to attach role2 to this same EC2 instance. They would be using the ec2 instance at different times.

I'm using the `aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile` command to attach the IAM profile to the EC2 instance before starting it up and then detaching the profile once I shut it down. I would like for each IAM user to be able to attach only a specific IAM role to this one EC2 instance.

Is this possible? Any ideas or examples? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the hint in the right direction! The solution below worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312767/971531

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following IAM policy for both users should be enough:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
            "Resource": "<arn-of-the-instance>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/<role-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above allows to only pass one specific role and `AssociateIamInstanceProfile` to one one specific instance.

However, this does not include detaching of the profiles from instances.

Comment: This helped and was exactly what I needed. Thank you Marcin. I will post my solution in a separate Answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that worked for me (thanks to Marcin for the hint in the right direction).

- I have two IAM users: `deploy-staging` and `deploy-production`.
- I have a single EC2 instance that can deploy to a staging environment or a production environment depending on the IAM role it has assumed.
- The `deploy-staging` IAM user has the following IAM policy attached. This policy will allow this user to start/stop the EC2 instance that is used to deploy code to **staging** and attach/detach the correct IAM role (`deploy-role-staging`) to that EC2 instance so it can have the correct permissions to deploy to staging. **That is the ONLY IAM role that this user will be able to attach to this EC2 instance**.

```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "ec2:StartInstances",
                  "ec2:DisassociateIamInstanceProfile",
                  "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
                  "ec2:StopInstances",
                  "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
                  "ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:ec2:*:account-id:security-group/sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account-id:instance/i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "arn:aws:ec2:*:account-id:security-group-rule/sgr-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              ]
          },
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                  "ec2:DescribeIamInstanceProfileAssociations"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iam:PassRole",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/deploy-role-staging"
          }
      ]
    }
```

- The `deploy-production` IAM user has the following IAM policy attached. This policy will allow this user to start/stop the EC2 instance that is used to deploy code to **production** and attach/detach the correct IAM role (`deploy-role-production`) to that EC2 instance so it can have the correct permissions to deploy to production. **That is the ONLY IAM role that this user will be able to attach to this EC2 instance**.

```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "ec2:StartInstances",
                  "ec2:DisassociateIamInstanceProfile",
                  "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
                  "ec2:StopInstances",
                  "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile",
                  "ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:ec2:*:account-id:security-group/sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account-id:instance/i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  "arn:aws:ec2:*:account-id:security-group-rule/sgr-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              ]
          },
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                  "ec2:DescribeIamInstanceProfileAssociations"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "iam:PassRole",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/deploy-role-production"
          }
      ]
    }
```

- The `deploy-role-staging` IAM role has policies attached to it that allow it to update the S3 buckets for staging and the Cloudfront distribution for staging.

```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                  "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:cloudfront::account-id:distribution/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              ]
          }
      ]
    }
```

```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "s3:PutObject",
                  "s3:ListBucket",
                  "s3:DeleteObject",
                  "s3:PutObjectAcl"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                  "arn:aws:s3:::stagingXXX.example.com",
                  "arn:aws:s3:::stagingXXX.example.com/*"
              ]
          }
      ]
    }
```

- The `deploy-role-production` IAM role has policies attached to it that allow it to update the S3 buckets for production and the Cloudfront distribution for production.

```
    They're the same as for staging, except the ID of Cloudfront distribution and the S3 bucket names are different.
```

**In Summary**: Each user will only be able to have the EC2 instance assume a particular role, thus giving that EC2 instance access to different resources.

Do not forget to write the code to actually start/stop the EC2 instance, attach/detach the IAM role using these CLI command samples (via /bin/bash):

```
    # Get the current IAM role association for the EC2 instance.
    EC2_IAM_ROLE_ASSOCIATION_ID=`aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations --filters Name=instance-id,Values=XXXXXXXXXXXX --query 'IamInstanceProfileAssociations[*].AssociationId' --output text --profile XXXX`

    # Only disassociate an IAM role if one is attached to the EC2 instance.
    if [ "$EC2_IAM_ROLE_ASSOCIATION_ID" ]; then
      # Disassociate any IAM role from the EC2 instance.
      aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id $EC2_IAM_ROLE_ASSOCIATION_ID --profile XXXX
    fi

    # Attach the correct IAM Role to the EC2 instance.
    EC2_IAM_ROLE_ASSOCIATION_ID=`aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id XXXXXXXXXXXX --iam-instance-profile Name="$IAM_ROLE" --query 'IamInstanceProfileAssociation.AssociationId' --output text --profile XXXX`

    # Disassociate any IAM Role from the EC2 instance.
    aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id $EC2_IAM_ROLE_ASSOCIATION_ID --query 'IamInstanceProfileAssociation.State' --output text --profile XXXX
```